# Não soma corretamente dados vindos de window.prompt

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um código em javascript e recebendo dados do usuário e gravando em um vetor, mas na hora de somar ele retorna todos os dados digitados

```
for(var contar = 0; contar < quantidade; contar++){

    var vei = window.prompt('Número de Veículos:')
    veiculos.push(vei)  
}
var total = veiculos.length
var soma = 0

for(var pos in veiculos){
    soma += veiculos[pos]
}
res.innerHTML += `Soma: ${soma}</br>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa converter o resultado de `window.prompt` para um inteiro, o resultado vem como uma string.

Faça `partInt()` para poder realizar a conversão, logo após a soma funciona corretamente.

```js
var veiculos = []
var quantidade = 5
for(var contar = 0; contar < quantidade; contar++){
    var vei = parseInt(window.prompt('Número de Veículos:'))
    veiculos.push(vei)  
}
var total = veiculos.length
var soma = 0

for(var pos in veiculos){
    soma += veiculos[pos]
}
console.log(`Soma: ${soma}`)
```